# How to map a request body in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have this data that format like this

```
router.post("/add", jsonParse, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.data) //[{"id":"someid","order":1,"configuration":"Config"}]//
})
```

I want to get the value of `id` the `someid`

I tried using

```
var deviceData = req.body.data.map(function (d) {
    return d.id;
  });
```

but is says that req.body.data.map is not a function

Comment: Is `req.body.data` a string perhaps?

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: Answer my question? Is it a string?

Comment: yes, it's a string of dictionary. exactly like this [{"id":"someid","order":1,"configuration":"Config"}]

Comment: `JSON.parse(req.body.data)`

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated, because you return a list in your response you just need to point also to the index 0.
Or if you are by design returning a list and you want only the id`s should be able to do the map

```js
    data = [{"id":"someid","order":1,"configuration":"Config"},{"id":"someid1","order":2,"configuration":"Config"},
    {"id":"someid2","order":3,"configuration":"Config"}]
    console.log(data) //[{"id":"someid","order":1,"configuration":"Config"}]//

    var deviceData = data[0]["id"];
    console.log(deviceData)
    const deviceDatalist = data.map(d => {
    //console.log(d.id)
    return d.id
  })
  console.log(deviceDatalist)
```

Comment: console.log(deviceData) are undefined.  console.log(deviceDatalist) map is not a function.